# No consigo mostrar más de dos registros mediante Database Query Builder de laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo un Form donde hay creado un **multiselect** el cual recojo la información mediante un arreglo de array, hasta ahí todo bien, lo que quiero básicamente es que si escojo dos options en select pueda mostrarlos mediante Query builder de laravel, he leido en la documentación que para realizar este tipo de cosas se debe usar el **->whereIn** acompañado de la variable array que en mi caso es **$usuarios,** pero de esta manera solo consigo imprimir el primer registro.

Allá va el código

Select con el arreglo array

```
<select style="WIDTH:100%;"  class="form-control select2" id="usuarios" name="usuarios[]" multiple   >

  @foreach($users as $user)
  <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
        @endforeach

</select>
```

Funcion controller

```
$usuarios = $request->usuarios;

  $fechaD = $request->fechaD;
  $fechaH = $request->fechaH;

  $horas = DB::table('partes_trabajo')


 ->select(
    'partes_trabajo.user_id as Usuario: ',
     DB::raw('SUM(desplazamiento) as Km'),
     DB::raw('SUM(peaje) as Peaje'),
     DB::raw('SUM(aparcamiento) as Aparcamiento'),
     DB::raw('SUM(otros_gastos) as Otros_gastos'),

                   )

  ->whereIn('user_id',$usuarios)

  ->get();


  print $horas;

  \Log::debug($horas);
```

Comment: ¿Verificaste que en `$usuarios` hay realmente un array de los IDs que buscas? Haz un `var_dump($usuarios);` para revisarlo.

Comment: Amigo, necesitas agrupar los usuarios, usa groupBy() antes del get. Porque sino lo que haces es sumar todo y te lo muestra en un registro.

Comment: he comprobado mediante var_dump que estan los registros y lo del goupBy() voy a probarlo

Comment: a lo del groupBy te refieres de esta forma?m ->groupBy()->get(); si es así no me funciona

Comment: el var_dum($usuarios)= array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "7" [1]=> string(2) "10" }, esta perfecto

Comment: Recuerda arrobar al usuario al que te dirijes @DavidRobles, para que se entere de que le estás hablando. `groupBy()` espera como parámetro el nombre de la columna https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: Lo tendre en cuenta para la próxima vez , muchas gracias me sirvieron de muchas las 3 respuestas para entender un poco mas el funcionamiento y a ver resuelto mi duda